# PhpMyAdmin: Results go by too fast and queries execute multiple times

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

PhpMyAdmin version: 3.4.9

Problems: two:

- When I execute a query, the results are shown on a new page for a split second and then I am returned to my query, so I can't actually see the results of my query. This only happens with structure manipulation quetries like  `DROP TABLE`, `CREATE TABLE`, etc.
- When I execute a query in the SQL tab of a database, the query is executed multiple times. For instance with a `DROP` query, the confirmation popup will show up multiple times (seemingly a random amount of times every time) and I will see multiple query result widgets. This is annoying and not helpful for when you want to say, insert lines.

I feel like these two issues are linked. Any solutions that don't require updating PHPMyAdmin? I can't do that as I have no access over the instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Heidi Sql to connect to your database if you have access to the host. Heidi is providing logs in the bottom part of the interface and you can scroll in them.

Comment: Try providing a link to the version of Heidi that you are referencing in your answer. Also please provide step by step instructions with pastable queries or commands if possible. This will increase the chance that your answer will be accepted.